# Ansible: Check a list and If found, delete an item or items

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that will run on lots of servers and on some of them, there are directories that need to be deleted. I could create a task for each server and the directories and use `when inventory_hostname=XXXX` but the problem is that the locations are unique along with the servers that they are on, so there would be over 300 such tasks and the output of the playbook will be swamped with all of the skips.

I thought about putting the list into *defaults/main.yml*, something like

```yaml
vars:
    server.eur.fqdn.net:
       - /path/to/dir
       - /path/to/other/dir
     servera.nam.fqdn.net:
       - /path/to/dira
     server2.apac.fqdn.net:
       - /path/to/dir2
       - /path/to/other/dir2
```

and then have a task to consume the list, something like

```yaml
- name: delete dir
     command: rm -rf {{ item }}
  with_items:  {{ vars }}
  when: item.key = "inventory_hostname"
```

But I can’t make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of task have to be achieved with the help of [your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html).
For example, with the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    nodes:
      hosts:
        server1.example.org:
          folder_to_delete:
            - /path/to/folder1
            - /path/to/folder2
        server2.example.org:
          folder_to_delete:
            - /path/to/folder3
            - /path/to/folder4
        server3.example.org:
          folder_to_delete:
            - /path/to/folder5
            - /path/to/folder6
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: nodes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ folder_to_delete | default([]) }}"
```

We can see that the correct folders are deleted on their own nodes and that the task gives a correct feedback — `ok` when the folder is already absent; `changed` when the folder was indeed deleted:

```
TASK [file] **************************************************************
changed: [server1.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder1)
ok: [server3.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder5)
ok: [server2.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder3)
changed: [server1.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder2)
changed: [server3.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder6)
ok: [server2.example.org] => (item=/path/to/folder4)
```

Also, by empty list as [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default), you could avoid having to define the variable `folder_to_delete` for nodes that do not need any clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Put the dictionary into *vars*

```yaml
  folder_to_delete:
    server.eur.fqdn.net:
      - /path/to/dir
      - /path/to/other/dir
    servera.nam.fqdn.net:
      - /path/to/dira
    server2.apac.fqdn.net:
      - /path/to/dir2
      - /path/to/other/dir2
```

Use it in the task

```yaml
    - name: delete dir
      debug:
        msg: "command: rm -rf {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ folder_to_delete[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
```

---

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
server.eur.fqdn.net
servera.nam.fqdn.net
server2.apac.fqdn.net
foo.bar.net
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    folder_to_delete:
      server.eur.fqdn.net:
        - /path/to/dir
        - /path/to/other/dir
      servera.nam.fqdn.net:
        - /path/to/dira
      server2.apac.fqdn.net:
        - /path/to/dir2
        - /path/to/other/dir2

  tasks:

    - name: delete dir
      debug:
        msg: "command: rm -rf {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ folder_to_delete[inventory_hostname]|d([]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [delete dir] ****************************************************************************
ok: [server.eur.fqdn.net] => (item=/path/to/dir) => 
  msg: 'command: rm -rf /path/to/dir'
ok: [server.eur.fqdn.net] => (item=/path/to/other/dir) => 
  msg: 'command: rm -rf /path/to/other/dir'
ok: [servera.nam.fqdn.net] => (item=/path/to/dira) => 
  msg: 'command: rm -rf /path/to/dira'
skipping: [foo.bar.net]
ok: [server2.apac.fqdn.net] => (item=/path/to/dir2) => 
  msg: 'command: rm -rf /path/to/dir2'
ok: [server2.apac.fqdn.net] => (item=/path/to/other/dir2) => 
  msg: 'command: rm -rf /path/to/other/dir2'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
foo.bar.net: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server.eur.fqdn.net: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server2.apac.fqdn.net: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
servera.nam.fqdn.net       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```